# Screen brightness problem on asus u82u with radeon HD6320

Tags: 16.04, brightness, asus, amd-graphics

I just upgraded my laptop to the newest ubuntu version 16.04 LTS and noticed that I can't change screen brightness. I have tried all methods with GRUB which I find in google, but still can't fix this issue. Now my Grub is:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

With this setup I stuck with the lowest brightness because it's better than sit with max brightness.
So maybe someone know how to fix this problem on new Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Answer (score 1):

Hi I think that this is a partial duplicate of this post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762643/change-brightness/775831#775831)

If you scroll down there is a workaround using a **brightness panel indicator**

Good luck.

Comment: I found better way to fix this, but thank you for ypr answer.

Answer (score 0):

I made brightness control work. It's not working as good as it was on ubuntu 15.10 before upgrade to 16.04, but it's something
My grub now is:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_osi=! acpi_backlight=native
idle=nomwait quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Maybe it would be helpful for someone.