# Brightness hotkey doesn't work on laptop asus k501ux [Ubuntu 16.04.1]

Tags: shortcut-keys, laptop, brightness, asus

I have laptop asus k501ux, just installed ubuntu and it seems every key works except brightness controls, in my case it is Fn+F5 (up) and F6(down). any idea why is that happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change brightness](http://askubuntu.com/questions/762643/change-brightness)

Comment: @wjandrea It is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @Pilot6 How is it different?

Comment: The laptop is different and the solution is different. Absolutely not related.

Comment: @pilot6 The linked question is just more broad (all Asus laptops instead of the k501ux specifically). I don't know enough about grub to talk about the solution, but it seems to be the same.

Comment: Anyway `acpi_osi=` is needed for this laptop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43252/discussion-between-wjandrea-and-pilot6).

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/q/816264/25388

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to the terminal and open grub file

> `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

2. Find

> `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

and change to this

> `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=native acpi_osi="`

3. Update grub

> `sudo update-grub`

4. Restart and it's done

*That worked on Asus k501ux laptop*

Comment: If my answer was helpful, you can accept it by clicking the check sign at the left of it, instead of editing in that it worked. @Giorgi Khmaladze

Comment: I will check the `acpi_backlight=native`. It is a new param.

Comment: This worked for me in Asus N501VW and Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks man :)

Comment: This is not sufficient in Asus Zenbook UX303UA, for instance, see if the problem still persists http://askubuntu.com/q/816264/25388