# Ubuntu 18.04 Cannot change display brightness or wake from Sleep on ASUS ROG laptop

Tags: brightness

I have ASUS ROG GL702, NVIDIA GTX 1070 graphics card.
Just installed 18.04.
Could adjust sound but not screen brightness with built in keyboard controls.
There wasn't even a brightness slider to adjust in the right corner by where the volume is.
And no brightness settings to change under the Power settings found in Activities.

Also when laptop goes to sleep, the screen stays black and I have to do a hard power down to reboot and get the screen back.

Does anybody know a way to fix this?
I am total newb, no programming experience.  Can open Terminal, but please fully explain any commands needed.
Thanks

edit: tried what's described in this post but that did not solve it: https://askubuntu.com/questions/804775/brightness-hotkey-doesnt-work-on-laptop-asus-k501ux-ubuntu-16-04-1?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: You should only ask one question at a time. As far as brightness adjustment goes this may or may not help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045624/how-to-switch-between-options-in-sys-class-backlight-to-solve-brightness-prob/1045763#1045763

Comment: i have the exact same laptop and the same issue, i think it's nvidia driver issue, running on nouveau driver and latest 390 nvidia, sometimes the laptop will boot in black screen, or keep flashing i posted on reddit, but no solution with people's solutions https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/94srns/ubuntu_not_booting_after_nvidia_driver_install/

Answer (score 3):

Asus G752VS brightness adjustment <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys work after these steps:

1. Change default grub configuration,e.g:

   ```
   $ sudo vi /etc/default/grub
   ```

   Add parameters `acpi_backlight=vendor` to set value like this:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
   ```
2. Update grub configuration:

   ```
   $ sudo update-grub
   ```
3. Reboot the system:

   ```
   $ reboot
   ```

After that you should have something like this:

```
$ ls -1 /sys/class/backlight/
asus-nb-wmis
```

4. Load Asus Notebook WMI module:

   ```
   $ sudo modprobe asus-nb-wmi
   ```

After that, the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys should work.

Comment: It didn't work, I can control the brigthness. But at least now the keyboard backlight is working.

Comment: try `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_backlight=native"`,   see https://askubuntu.com/a/1508733/34298

Answer (score 0):

I don't run Ubuntu so thought was using lightdm but apparently its GDM. So you can try that instead of powering down. (sudo service gdm restart) or (sudo systemctl restart gdm.service) not sure which one. As far as the brightness issue, have you tried enabling Handle display brightness under power management? Are you using 3rd party drivers, and if so can you adjust from Nvidia panel?

Answer (score 0):

I am **ASUS TUF-17** series user.
and currently installed 20.04 LTS focal-fosa release in it.

So here is my solution for controlling so bright white light on your laptop, hope it'll helped out for other users too-

First of all,

Plzzz, Plzzz, Plzzz didn't do anything for your brightness ,if you have ***ASUS A15,A17 or any ASUS ROG series or gaming laptop***.

I tried all of the possible ways to do so-
Neither changing the

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"

is worked,nor

> any changes in grub file config.

or **You will get stucked into infinity reboot** .

*The simplest way to reduce eye strain is to install **Redshift** App for linux.

**#1) Redshift**

you can, using this command-*

```
sudo apt-get install redshift

sudo apt-get install redshift-gtk

sudo apt update
```

*This app is so beautifully optimises brightness intensity automatically,You just didn't need to control brightness.*

Now, You can use different IDE's with having white background easily in late night hours.

Some More App I personally suggest you for your eye-care is-

**#2**

> Safe Eyes   ____"available in ubuntu store" .......(it'll let you make some breaks in long working hours)

**#3**

> Screen Shader .......(it is a chrome extension for more light filtering)

***That's ALL.
Now, You didn't need to worry about your Brightness***