Install Ubuntu 22.04 on a ASUS ROG Flow X16
Is it possible to install Ubuntu on a ASUS ROG Flow X16 (GV601RM-M5115W with AMD Ryzen 7-6800HS and NVIDIA RTX 3060)?
I have checked the Ubuntu compatibility lists on the Ubuntu site, but there were no entries yet for this model.
I would like to use it alongside with Windows 11 on another partition. So, I tried the USB Ubuntu live Installation and noticed that the display brightness settings are not working and the keyboard backlight shortcut-keys aren't either.
Are there any more specific problems or considerations I should be aware of?
Anyone with any experiences with this model?
How can I solve those issues?

Does this answer your question? Will my device work with Ubuntu?

How could I edit this question, so my answer would fit?

Try installing Ubuntu or at least running a bootable Ubuntu USB live session. Then list whatever issues or errors you encounter and add them to your question. This will make your question more specific and possibly it will also make it more unique.

Your answer is mostly a generic install Ubuntu guide with nothing specific to this device in it, plus a grab bag of random and otherwise unrelated suggestions - some of those could be individual QAs, but in general, I don't see how they relate to this question, and so far no evidence as to how this device is in any way special.

Sure I had some problems with the default install: the missing brightness button and the keyboard-backlight. I'm sure, I will run into more problems soon and will add them to the answer too

The backlight thing, for example, is an individual issue, which if you'd posted as an actual question, would have actually been a duplicate. But you haven't posted any actual problems in the question, making it too vague - ah now I see you have edited to do so. Now, the problem is your question is too unfocused.

As a long time SE user, you should be well aware that a question shouldn't have multiple problems in it.

Install Ubuntu 22.04 along Windows 11 on ASUS ROG Flow X16
It works pretty much like the default installation, so:

Backup of your important Windows files! Then resize your Windows Partition in the partition manager to get free space for Ubuntu. Now you should be able to install Ubuntu in a dual-boot configuration:

Install Ubuntu on a USB Device with Rufus

In Boot-Settings choose the USB Stick with your Ubuntu install Image


Tweaks for the Asus Rog flow x16 on Ubuntu

fix brightness buttons
Edit your /etc/default/grub file:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_backlight=native"

source: https://askubuntu.com/a/1508733/34298

The AURA setting didn't work, so I used rogauracore to set the color of the keyboard-backlight and then added new keyboard shortcuts to dim and increase brightness: https://github.com/rubo77/rogauracore-scripts


Suggestions

Remap M4 key to Print
Since there is no Print key on this Laptop, you can remap the PRINT key to the extra M4 Key: go to Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Screenshots

fix HEVC videos: by default Ubuntu Totem cannot play any Vidoes from my Pixel phone, so I had to
sudo apt remove gstreamer1.0-vaapi

source: https://askubuntu.com/a/1406276/34298



that's strange. I couldn't even boot into the livecd usb flash of Ubuntu. tried 22.04 and 24.04

maybe you didn't install the Ubuntu on USB with Rufus?

Installed with Rufus. Even tried USB flash created with both boot methods (UEFI and Bios).

It just spams in console while booting with the error "BadTLP pcie" for the Nvidia RTX 3070 Ti.

did you try other linuxes? plain debian? Or maybe this helps? https://chatgpt.com/share/66f5a35b-66d8-8010-bf65-2047b8dd8f44

thanks. tried almost everything with no success. the one, that didn't is using the <5.5 kernel versions.
it's interesting that everything works fine in windows.
